# How to use EXTJS proxy params in C# backend?

Tags: c#, extjs, proxy, extjs4, gridpanel

I want to use a paging toolbar for my GridPanel.

How can I use the params from the store/proxy in the back end?

For example,

`autoLoad: { params: { start: 0, limit: 5} }`,
`autoLoad: {start: 0, limit: 25}`

or the params described here :

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.Ajax

I have no clue.

Comment: What is your backend framework? ASP.NET WebForms or MVC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation link you provided](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.Ajax) describes it clearly. When the client asks for data from server, it formulates a HTTP request and sends it to server to receive the data. The HTTP request URL is generated based on values of `start` and `limit` parameters like this:

```
/users?start=0&limit=5
```

On the server you'd read parameters from request:

```
System.Web.HttpContext context = System.Web.HttpContext.Current;
int start, limit;
if ( int.TryParse(context.Request["start"], out start) &&
    int.TryParse(context.Request["limit"], out limit) )
{
    // send the data to client
}
else
{
    // error handling
}
```

---

A side note: If you don't like parameters named `start` and `limit`, you can reconfigure them to some other names:

```
var proxy = new Ext.data.proxy.Ajax({
    url: '/users',
    startParam: 'startIndex',
    limitParam: 'limitIndex'
});
```

Then the request would look like

```
/users?startIndex=0&limitIndex=5
```

and you'd read `context.Request["startIndex"]` and `context.Request["limitIndex"]` respectively in the backend.